# Android Studio: Error:(58, 13) Failed to resolve: com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.3.5

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to add this [Library](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)

But when Sync the Android Studio project following error is coming ..
Error:(58, 13) Failed to resolve: com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.3.5

I'm struck with this, please help me...

Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"

    }
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kennyc1012/maven' }

}

repositories{
    flatDir{
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.7.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.2.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.JayFang1993:DropDownMenu:96d390f9c4'
    compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.mrengineer13:snackbar:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'

}

dependencies {

    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.3.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this dependency is available on maven central. Try to add the central maven repo to your repositories and resync again.

```
repositories {
  maven {
    url "https://jitpack.io"
  }
  maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kennyc1012/maven' }
  mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Could you try with jCenter() and mavenCentral() only?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the

```
jcenter()
```

in the Project build.gradle file with

```
mavenCentral()
```